# Can't stop process, no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.8080.pid (Thin::PidFileNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, git, capistrano, capistrano3

I am installing app from my private git repository. I installed all dependencies and I am using Capistrano.I am able to run app successfully on my local machine.I am using rails -v 3.2.14 and ruby -v ruby 1.9.3p362 and linux server

when I am running `cap production deploy` I am getting error

`......
....
sftp upload complete
  * executing "cd /var/www/vhosts/..../apps/login/current && bundle exec thin -C /var/www/vhosts/....../apps/login/current/thin.yml -O restart"
    servers: ["......net"]
    [root@emerge126.mysitehosting.net] executing command
 ** [out :: root@........net] Stopping server on 127.0.0.1:8080 ...
 ** [out :: root@........net] /var/www/vhosts/......./apps/.../shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:131:in 'send_signal': Can't stop process, no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.8080.pid (Thin::PidFileNotFound)`

My **deploy.rb** file require

```
'bundler/capistrano'
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
require 'capistrano-thin'

set :stages, ["staging", "production"]
set :default_stage, "production"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
set :ssh_options, {
 config: false
}

set :application, "myapp"
set :repository,  "https://........git"
set :scm, :git
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :branch, 'master'
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/vhosts/......../apps/#{application}"


 set :keep_releases, 5
 set :use_sudo, false

 set :thin_servers, 1
 set :thin_port, 8081

 namespace :deploy do
    namespace :db do
      desc "Seed the database"
      task :seed, :roles => :db do
      # on_rollback { deploy.db.restore }
      run_remote_rake('db:seed')
      end
   end


  task :symlink_configs do
   run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
   run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/auth.yml #{current_path}/config/auth.yml"
  end

end

 before "deploy:restart", "deploy:symlink_configs"
 after "deploy:update", "deploy:cleanup"

 def run_remote(cmd)
   run "cd #{current_path} && #{cmd}"
 end

 def run_remote_rake(task)
    rails_env = fetch(:rails_env, 'integration')
    run_remote("rake #{task} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}")
 end
```

My **production.rb** file

```
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/vhosts/....../apps/#    {application}"

server 'root@.......net', :web, :app, :db, :primary => true
set :thin_port, 8081
set :rails_env, 'production'
```

I need some help. Its a multi rails app server. Please ask any more info if you need. I have also replaced site and github url with .... because of site security.

Comment: if you log into your server and run `ps -ef | grep thin`, do you see a thin process running? If so, was it started using the same cap deploy you posted here? Your deploy scripts are trying to stop an existing thin process, but the PID file for that process is not found in the expected location (tmp/pids/thin.8080.pid), so the deploy fails.

Comment: when i run ` ps -ef | grep thin' ` I get 
`root     11308  4670  0 13:55 pts/3    00:00:00 grep thin'`

Comment: then thin is not running, so there is no process to stop. Can you start thin manually on your server? If so then afterwards you should be able to successfully deploy.

Comment: No i can not start thin manually thin start
No adapter found for

Comment: thin -v
thin 1.5.0 codename Knife

Comment: try running `bundle exec thin -C /var/www/vhosts/stark.emergeinchosting.com/apps/login/current/thin.yml -O start` from inside /var/www/vhosts/stark.emergeinchosting.com/apps/login/current

Comment: Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

Comment: this is because when this error happens  [deploy:create_symlink] rolling back

Comment: should I manually create Gemfile

Comment: has the app ever been deployed to this server?

Comment: This app is running on old server and I have to migrate it to this server. Yes there are other app running on this server.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using this gem: https://github.com/freego/capistrano-thin, but I do not see `after 'deploy:publishing', 'thin:restart'` in your deploy.rb. If you comment out `require 'capistrano-thin'`, are you able to deploy?

Comment: Yes I am able to deploy now... but is it ok and how to i run my app

Comment: thin start
`>> Using rack adapter
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:297:in initialize': No such file or directory - /var/www/vhosts/stark.emergeinchosting.com/apps/login/releases/20160210192934/config/database.yml `

Comment: That's a different problem. Now you have to get your database.yml on the server. The app won't start without it. Once you have that resolved you should be able to successfully run `thin -C /var/www/vhosts/stark.emergeinchosting.com/apps/login/current/thin.yml -O start`, then uncomment `require 'capistrano-thin'`, and successfully run your deploy script with a thin restart.

Comment: OK Thank you sir, I really struggled with this a lot. Thank You

Comment: you're welcome, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no thin process running on your server, that's why you're getting  the `Can't stop process, no PID found` error. I suggest starting thin manually so your deploy script can then successfully restart it.